# Difference between String and string

Tags: java, string

When using Java, what is the difference between the two following assignments:

```
String upperCaseDataType = "myName";
string lowerCaseDataType = "myName";
```

Do the 2 mean the same at compile time, just like in C#?

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: If you know that Java is case sensitive, then what is the question? Are you asking what would the second line do if it compiled even though it doesn't?

Comment: Java doesn't have implicit casting so there is no way to make `string s= "hello";` compile (without hacking the JDK)  Did you want to confirm that there isn't a way to make it compile?

Comment: In short, they are different as one compiles and the other doesn't.

Comment: It is unclear what your question really is. Did you mean the second line to be `String s = "myName":` - ion other words, are you asking whether "myName" can be assigned to two different String instances (s and S) ?

Comment: Well, that's what I call lazy. Was 1 minute research to much to ask for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`string` is not a class or type in Java

Answer (score 6):

No. `string s = "myName";` is not legal Java, and will not compile. Also, those are assignments (not assertions).

Comment: @Rustam No it won't, because the compiler won't allow you to sub-class the `final` `java.lang.String` (and a `String` constant `""` will not be assignable to your `string`).

Comment: @MicheleLaFerla Stop manipulating valid answers.